# Concatenate N char arrays on left hand side efficiently, C

Tags: c, string, concatenation

Suppose I have N char arrays that I would like to concatenate together.  Each char array is stored in an individual struct.  In order to access the char array in stuct1 I need to access struct2, to access struct2 I need to access struct3, etc (imagine a single linked list with the head at structN and tail at struct1).

I want to concatenate each char array from each struct so that the char array from struct1 appears first and char array from structN appears last.

For example, suppose my char arrays associated with struct1, struct2, and struct3 have contents "A", "B", "C".  I want to get the resulting char array "ABC".  However, as stated above, to visit structX I must first visit structX+1.  It would therefore be much more efficient to concatenate these char arrays on the left; I wouldn't have to keep going through all the structs.

Is there a way to do this efficiently in C (i.e. strcat, snprintf, etc) or do I have to manually manipulate each char array to get what I want (or go through the list, save pointers to the structs, and work my way back)?

Edit (clarity)
Suppose I have a single linked, linked list.  Each element has a char array.  I want to concatenate the char arrays in reverse order.  Is there a way to do this without going through the list twice?  I know the maximum size of all char arrays at runtime but I don't know their individual sizes until I visit each element of the list (when I visit element X I know the size of the char array stored at X)

Comment: What's the maximum value of `N`?

Comment: Depends, it could be as small as a few dozen to several hundred.  One thing I could do is create an array of pointers to these structs by going through the list of them, save each pointer, then work my way backwards.  This would give O(2N) which is decidedly better than the alternative, but at the same time is twice as expensive as just going through once.  Given the size of N it won't make too much difference.  This question is more to see if there is a way to do it by only going through the list once.

Comment: Why not just write your own function to prepend one string to another?

Comment: So your linked list is 3->2->1?

Comment: @Yunnosch yes.  But I want to concatenate the char arrays stored in each in the opposite direction.

Comment: Indeed it is possible but you have to make sure that the buffer you copy to is big enough to fit those objects' contents or use `realloc` at each iteration what can be slow. Make some benchmarks with O(2N) (when you allocate memory only once) and the O(N) approach, then you will see what's the better choice.

Comment: What if you have an interface to access the final combined array instead of a big concatenated array? WIll it be fine?

Comment: @DavidBowling wouldn't that be inefficient?  I believe that would result in writing the same char array over and over unless I am miss understanding what you mean.

Comment: I understood correctly then (finally). May I recommend trying to visualise more? Maybe talk about "Cccc", "Bbbb", "Aaaa" -> "AaaaBbbbCccc". The info is already in your question I admit, but you could help other slow-thinkers like me... ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch In retrospect it is a bit confusing.  I probably should have numbered the structs in the opposite direction.

Comment: Do the structures store the lengths of the strings?  The structures are all the same type, aren't they?  Building a list in the correct order and then allocating the required target space and copying is likely to be fastest.  Trying to prepend repeatedly will be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: *"This would give O(2N) which is decidedly better than the alternative, but at the same time is twice as expensive as just going through once."* That's actually not true, since copying a single string to the output buffer is an O(M) operation, where M is the average length of the strings. So overall, the string copies are O(M*N), which swamps O(N) unless M is tiny.

Comment: @user3386109 regardless of how many times I go through the list I have to write so many times to the output buffer (at least N times).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed, I can allocate enough space for everything before hand.  However, I'm not aware of anything in like snprintf that allows concatenation on the left hand side.  So I could do what your saying by going through the list essentially twice, allocating enough space, then writing.  Can I do it by only going through once though?

Comment: Yes, but the point is that the extra time for the forward pass through the list may only change the run time from 3.0 to 3.1 seconds, since traversing the list is fast compared to copying the strings. And the forward pass doesn't do any copying.

Comment: I don't know whether you can work magic going through the list just once, but I assume not since you asked the question.  I know I can't work magic, and I'd have to go through the list twice.  The only issues are what's the best way of handling that reverse traversal.  I assume there's a good reason why you don't keep the list in the sane order so you don't need to traverse twice.  As to the copying, if you know all the lengths, you can arrange to `memmove()` — or `memcpy()` — the data to the target string.  You certainly won't be using `strcat()` or any of its relatives.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it is in a sane order. I'm using dijkstra's shortest path algorithm which by construction build results in paths that are reversed.  Getting things into a sane order is what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: You've not said much about how long the strings are — whether they're a few bytes each or a few kilobytes (or megabytes, or bigger).  Or how variable the string lengths are.  Can you do a heuristic allocation (number of entries in the list times average length) and adjust if necessary?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler They could be potentially very long (It's hard to say ahead of time).  Really though this question isn't about finding a solution that will work.  Going through the list twice works.  I'm just curious if there is a better way

Comment: @HXSP1947 I assume you want the algorithm to have a complexity of `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the final string? Or do you want it to be just linear in terms of the number of strings? Do you have the length of each string stored in the struct? If that is available it can be done easily.

Comment: What's your definition of "very long"?  I gave 6 orders of magnitude; which of them apply?  And how variable also matters — if they're all uniformly 10 KiB ± 1 KiB, that's one thing; if there's typically one that's 100 KiB but most of them are 10-100 bytes, that's another thing.  You're not scoping the size very clearly,  But it really doesn't matter very much.  You're going to need to go through the list twice to avoid quadratic behaviour if you tried to insert data in front of already set-up chunks.  Or you arrange to copy the data in reverse order and end up reversing the entire string. Or…

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I'll know the maximum length of all strings at runtime.  So an algorithm would ideally be linear in the number of structs.

Comment: Your algorithm will have a time proportional to the sum of the lengths of the strings, and the number of structures will be a second-order effect.

Comment: @HXSP1947 Just create a huge string and `memcpy`, individual strings at the write places.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I know the maximum size of the string, not their actual sizes until I visit each struct.  How would I know the right memory addresses?

Comment: Show your structures in the question. Explain what you've tried.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed.  Like I said though, this question is more out of curiosity.  I know how to solve the problem.  I'm curious if a better solution exists.  The data structure is essentially a linked list.  Each element of the linked list is a struct with multiple fields one of which is a char array.  I want to concatenate theses arrays backwards.

Comment: But you've not said or shown whether one of the other fields is the length of the string in the char array (or the length of the non-string — no null terminator — data in the array).   However, for my money, you'll need to make the two passes over the list, but that's a trivial cost compared to the copying you seem likely to need to do.  If you don't record the lengths of the arrays in the structure, you've added a lot of cost to the operation.  You must have known how long they are as you created them; don't throw valuable information away. Don't forget you can `realloc()` to shrink an array.

Comment: Do you know how many elements are in the list before you start the concatenation process.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  No, I don't.  If that was necessary for a O(N) solution though I could keep a counter that increments each time I create a new element in the list (during its construction).

Comment: OK; you're snookered.  Go through the list twice, once forwards, once backwards. After going through forwards, you can devise methods to go backwards, either using recursion or creating a reverse list as you go.  Compute the space needed on the way through forwards; allocate the space when you reach the end, and then go backwards doing the copying.  And since you've got the data in the wrong order, you're going to need to allow enough space and/or time to get it in the right order.  There's no magic; you can trade space for time, but TANSTAAFL.

Comment: @HXSP1947 even if you don't know the length of each string, you can count it using `strlen`, the total overhead of that would be sum of the length of each string which fits in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which prints a linked list in reverse, you should be able to modify it for your concat problem, by passing in a char buffer parameter.

```
void ReversePrint(Node *head)
{
  if (head == NULL)
      return;
  else if (head->next == NULL) {
      printf("%d\n", head->data);
  } else {
      ReversePrint(head->next);
      printf("%d\n", head->data);
  }
}
```

The trick is to make the recursive call BEFORE you do the actual work, so that you begin processing with the last node and then process everything else as you unroll.  Then you can avoid the left-handed concatenation issue, you simply concatenate at the end as you normally would like to do.

Comment: This requires space that is linear in number of elements of the linked list. Which is generally not acceptable.

Comment: Space as in, for the call stack, or for the storage buffer?

Comment: Space on the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple bench to check which approach is more efficient:

- using `realloc` on each iteration
- iterate two times over the list, first time to get the size, second one to copy the strings

Element of the list which I used in this bench is a structure:

```
struct elem
{
    char *str;
    size_t size;
};
```

This is an element of a doubly linked list (I used [this](https://github.com/KKoovalsky/DoublyLinkedList) this implementation of the list).

Then I generated some strings in such a way:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; j ++)
{
    char * str = malloc(SINGLE_STRING_LEN + 1);
    memset(str, gimme_next_char(), SINGLE_STRING_LEN);
    str[SINGLE_STRING_LEN] = '\0';

    struct elem e;
    e.str = str;
    e.size = SINGLE_STRING_LEN;

    dl_list_insert_at_tail(&l, (void *) &e);
}
```

`SINGLE_STRING_LEN` has value `10` and `gimme_next_char` returns chars from `A` to `Z` cyclically. `i` is a value from an outer loop which allows to control how many items are inserted to the list. I tested the operation for 100, 200, ... , 900 elements.

The first approach looks like that:

```
char *concat_str = NULL;
size_t concat_str_len = 1; // Remember about '\0' character
for_each_in_dl_list(struct elem, e, l)
{
    size_t new_len = concat_str_len + e->size;
    concat_str = realloc(concat_str, new_len);
    strcpy(&concat_str[concat_str_len - 1], e->str);
    concat_str_len = new_len;
}
```

(I assumed that `sizeof(char) == 1`).
As you can see on each iteration `realloc` is used to resize the string. Then the string from the list is appended to the resulting string using `strcpy`. Basically you get there `O(N * (M + realloc complexity))` where `M` is `strcpy` function complexity.

The second approach:

```
size_t concat_str_len = 1;
for_each_in_dl_list(struct elem, e, l)
    concat_str_len += e->size;

char *concat_str = malloc(concat_str_len);
concat_str_len = 1;
for_each_in_dl_list(struct elem, e, l)
{
    size_t new_len = concat_str_len + e->size;
    strcpy(&concat_str[concat_str_len - 1], e->str);
    concat_str_len = new_len;
}
```

Here we firstly get the size of the whole final string and then we iterate through the list to append each of the strings from the list. You get there `O(N + N * M + malloc complexity)`.

The dynamically allocated data must be freed but I don't want to paste this code here as it's useless in this topic.

I've invoked the first program and the second program ~20 times to compute an average of the execution time:

```
Elems on the list    |  105  |  305  |  505  |  705  |  905
First approach [us]  |   9   |  25   |  42   |  54   |   67
Second approach [us] |   6   |  14   |  25   |  31   |   39
```

The second approach is quite faster. I could also see that the standard deviation for the first approach is much bigger (about 6 times bigger for 905 elements on the list). This is probably a cause of multiple calls to `realloc` function as the first approach is more system dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider following code if you don't mind doing some pointer ugliness.

```
struct Ptr {
    char *alloc_;
    char *start_;
};
struct Ptr concat(Node *head) {
    Ptr ptr;
    ptr.alloc_ = malloc(maxSizeOfCharArray);
    ptr.start_ = ptr.alloc_ + maxSizeOfCharArray - 2;
    *(ptr.start_ + 1) = 0;
    while (head != NULL){
        ptr.start_ -= strlen(head->str)
        memcpy(ptr.start_, head->str, strlen(head->str));
        head = head->next;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

After all of this you are responsible for freeing the alloc_ memory. Don't know if it will be faster than naive solution.